# Inject parameters to constructor through annotation in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am using Spring Boot annotation configuration. I have a class whose constructor accepts 2 parameters (string, another class).

Fruit.java

```java
public class Fruit {
    public Fruit(String FruitType, Apple apple) {
            this.FruitType = FruitType;
            this.apple = apple;
        }
}
```

Apple.java

```java
public class Apple {

}
```

I have a class  that needs to autowire the above class by injecting parameters to the constructor("iron Fruit",Apple class)

Cook.java

```java
public class Cook {

    @Autowired
    Fruit applefruit;
}
```

The cook class need to autowire Fruit class with parameters("iron Fruit",Apple class)

The XML configuration looks like this:

```xml
<bean id="redapple" class="Apple" />
<bean id="greenapple" class="Apple" />
<bean name="appleCook" class="Cook">
          <constructor-arg index="0" value="iron Fruit"/>
          <constructor-arg index="1" ref="redapple"/>
</bean>
<bean name="appleCook2" class="Cook">
          <constructor-arg index="0" value="iron Fruit"/>
          <constructor-arg index="1" ref="greenapple"/>
</bean>
```

How to achieve it using annotation configuration only?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apple must be a spring-managed bean:

```
@Component
public class Apple{

}
```

Fruit as well:

```
@Component
public class Fruit {

    @Autowired
    public Fruit(
        @Value("iron Fruit") String FruitType,
        Apple apple
        ) {
            this.FruitType = FruitType;
            this.apple = apple;
        }
}
```

Note the usage of `@Autowired` and `@Value` annotations.

Cook should have `@Component` too.

**Update**

Or you could use `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations:

```
@Configuration 
public class Config {

    @Bean(name = "redapple")
    public Apple redApple() {
        return new Apple();
    }

    @Bean(name = "greeapple")
    public Apple greenApple() {
        retturn new Apple();
    }

    @Bean(name = "appleCook")
    public Cook appleCook() {
        return new Cook("iron Fruit", redApple());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have improved my question a bit.
If I need to inject different apple(redapple or green apple), what to do.
Different beans with same class .
the Fruit class constructor parameters must be injected with redapple or greenapple

Comment: What if Apple is not spring-managed and from a third party library that can't be modified?

Comment: @Claus then you can use \@Configuration and \@Bean annotations

Comment: How?  Remember any changes to the Apple class is off limit.

Comment: Isn't your second example problematic? By invoking redApple() in the Method appleCook you will NOT get the global SpringBean "redapple", but instead will create a new instance...

Comment: @Falco Spring is smart enough to handle this. See 2.2.2 Injecting Dependencies example here http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: You are right. But this cost me a lot of nerves, because it only works when the class is annotated with \@Configuration. Else the magic doesn't work, they should immediately print a warning on finding a \@Bean Method in a class without \@Configuration