# How to initialize Spring bean with dynamic arguments at run-time which is not prototype bean?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to initialize Spring bean with request scope, and lazy initialization from another object (attributes) that are not managed by Spring.
Here is the bean definition :

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request")
@Lazy
public class LazyClass {

 protected String name;

}
```

How do I init the 'name' attribute at runtime ?

Comment: Little code will help others.

Comment: I have added the class definition

Comment: Did you try this "@Autowire @Lazy private LazyClass lazyClass" ?

Comment: I don't understand,  why do we need 'private' access modifier ?

Comment: I don't need to inject this class (bean), but to initialize it.

Comment: I think this answer solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/30532741/2950010

Comment: No. the "name" attribute in my case is not a bean and I need to initialize it at run-time, not via static XML file or configuration java file.

Comment: Add setter for that property and call that setter when you need to set new value for that property

Comment: Ok. That's what I was doing. But I thought maybe there might another way

Answer (score -1):

It may not be the best solution but you can set the value of `name` into a `System` property and get it where you need it in your class.

Setting the value somewhere in a non-spring class:

```
// myProperty is the name of the property
// name is the value you want to store
System.setProperty("myProperty",name);
```

Getting inside your class:

```
// Caution: the name of the property must be the same as it was when it was set
String name = System.getProperty("myProperty);
```

The getting method can be called in the constructor of your bean class as it is marked as `@Lazy`.

EDIT:

Another way is to create a setter for the field `name` and set its value when you need it.